# Modify Date Created Attribute

Tags: .net, windows, ntfs, fat32, datecreated

How to modify "Date Created" attribute of files and folders in FAT32 and NTFS using .NET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the [`File.SetCreationTime` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setcreationtime.aspx), or the writable [`FileInfo.CreationTime` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime.aspx).

Comment: wow! too easy! I googled that and faced some strange assembly codes! thank you, +1, what a stupid question I asked!